# How to add label(annotation) to each plotting dot on R scatterplot3d

Tags: r, annotations, data-annotations, scatter-plot, scatterplot3d

The data formate "NB" is as follows.

```
> head(NB)
   time    speed  traffic  density
1 06:00 44.04854 304.6616 108.4641
2 06:10 43.73164 332.3510 111.6164
3 06:20 43.35056 359.2273 114.8773
4 06:30 42.91960 382.6465 118.5487
5 06:40 42.42904 400.3864 121.8942
6 06:50 41.91823 415.5429 124.9405

> str(NB)
'data.frame':   85 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ time   : Factor w/ 144 levels "00:00","00:10",..: 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 ...
 $ speed  : num  44 43.7 43.4 42.9 42.4 ...
 $ traffic: num  305 332 359 383 400 ...
 $ density: num  108 112 115 119 122 ...
```

I have used the below code to make a 3d graph. I want to know how to add the first "time" column to the 3d graph plotted dots and label "time"(06:00, 06:10 .... 20:00)

```
zz <- scatterplot3d(x=NB[,2],y=NB[,3], z=NB[,4],main=naljja,xlab="speed",ylab="traffic",zlab="density",pch=1,color = "blue",grid = TRUE)
```

[image: image result from upper code(zz)]

Answer (score 2):

Try taking your `zz` object (result of `scatterplot3d`) and use the `xyz.convert` function to transform the coordinates from 3D (x, y, z) to a 2D-projection (x, y). Then use can use `text` and add labels to the graph from the `time` column (first column). In this case, I used `cex` to reduce the text size, and `pos` to place label to the right of the points.

```
library(scatterplot3d)

zz <- scatterplot3d(x = NB[,2], y = NB[,3], z = NB[,4], 
                    xlab = "speed", ylab = "traffic", zlab = "density", 
                    pch = 1, color = "blue", grid = TRUE)

zz.coords <- zz$xyz.convert(NB[,2], NB[,3], NB[,4]) 

text(zz.coords$x, 
     zz.coords$y,             
     labels = NB[,1],               
     cex = .5, 
     pos = 4)
```

**Plot**

[image: 3d plot with text labels on points]

**Data**

```
NB <- structure(list(time = c("06:00", "06:10", "06:20", "06:30", "06:40", 
"06:50"), speed = c(44.04854, 43.73164, 43.35056, 42.9196, 42.42904, 
41.91823), traffic = c(304.6616, 332.351, 359.2273, 382.6465, 
400.3864, 415.5429), density = c(108.4641, 111.6164, 114.8773, 
118.5487, 121.8942, 124.9405)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

**Reference**

https://www.r-bloggers.com/2012/01/getting-fancy-with-3-d-scatterplots/